# osticket with ticket id in subject doesn't generate new ticket

Tags: php, ticket-system, osticket

I got mail with subject 'WG: [ticket#29478] H...'. I forward it to the osTicket system, but new ticket was not created. When I delete '[ticket#29478]' or change the name of ticket in the subject then new ticket is created.
Can someone explain me why no new ticket is created if subject contain [ticket#xxxxx] and how can I fix this??? I use osTicket v1.6.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

If a ticket number is attached to the email it will be associated with that existing ticket, rather than generating a new one.  I don't know of any way to disable this function.